# Capitalize the first character of most words except some exceptions using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript regex which capitalizes the first character of most words except some exceptions:

There are two issues with this regex that I have not resolved. The very first letter should always be capitalized. The second letter of every word should be lower case.

Here is an example of how it is working:

```js
function capitalizeFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?!^)\b(?!(?:of|the)\b)([a-z])/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
}


console.log(capitalizeFirst('the fox JUMP off of THE street'));
```

Where it should be returning this: ('of' and 'the' should be lower case except if on first word). Also it should lower case the rest of the word:

The Fox Jump Off of the Street

I could not find an answer to this specific question during a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution. This is an explanation of fix:

- The toLowerCase was added in the beginning to lower all characters
- The regex was modified accordingly to handle this:
  [image]
  https://regex101.com/

```js
function capitalizeFirst(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/\b(?!(?!^)(?:of|the)\b)([a-z])/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(capitalizeFirst('the fox JUMP off of THE street'));
```